# Jenkins pipeline - how to read input parameter, split its value and pass the values to build job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline configured which calls different build job and passes different values to the job. I have multiple suites configured which would trigger jobs to run in parallel.
Here is the sample code:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    string(name: 'ARRAY', defaultValue: 'AR1234', description: 'Enter array. ')
    string(name: 'email_recepients', defaultValue: 'abc@xyz.com', description: 'Enter email id')
    choice(name: 'regression_suite', choices: ['suite1', 'suite2', 'all'], description: '')
    choice(name: 'PRODUCT_RELEASE', choices: ['R1', 'R2'], description: 'Release on which test is being run')
    choice(name: 'interface', choices: ['int1', 'int2'], description: 'interface to use?')
    choice(name: 'Update_UTMS', choices: ['false', 'true'], description: 'Update UTMS/QC? If yes, select true')
    string(name: 'testset_id_1', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'If Suite1, enter xxx ID <br> \
                       If Suite2, enter yyy ID <br> ')
    string(name: 'testset_id_2', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'If Suite1, enter zzz ID <br> \
                       If Suite2, enter aaa ID <br> ')
    string(name: 'testset_id_3', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'If Suite1, enter bbb ID <br> \
                       If Suite2, enter ccc ID <br>')
    string(name: 'testset_id_4', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'If Suite1, enter ddd ID <br> \
                       If Suite2, enter fff ID <br>')
    string(name: 'testset_id_5', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'If Suite1, enter eee ID')
    string(name: 'testset_all', defaultValue: '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', description: 'All of Testset IDs')
  }

  stages {
    stage('Starting Suite1 (Parallel execution)') {

      when {
        expression {
          params.regression_suite == "suite1" || params.regression_suite == "all"
        }
      }

      steps {
        script {
          try {
            catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
            suite1()
          }

          } finally {
            echo "Suite1 completed, but we continue"
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Starting Suites2 (Parallel execution)') {

      when {
        expression {
          params.regression_suite == "suite2" || params.regression_suite == "all"
        }
      }

      steps {
        script {
          try {
            catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
            suite2()
          }

          } finally {
            echo "Suite2 completed, but we continue"
          }
        }
      }
    }

    
  }
}
def suite1() {
  parallel(
  bla1: {
    build job: 'sd_regression',
    parameters: [string(name: 'ARRAY', value: "${params.ARRAY}"), string(name: 'email_recepients', value: "${params.email_recepients}"), string(name: 'test_type', value: 'bla1'), string(name: 'Interface', value: params.interface + '_0'),booleanParam(name: 'Update_UTMS', value: params.Update_UTMS), string(name: 'utms_testset_id', value: "${params.testset_id_1}"), string(name: 'PRODUCT_RELEASE', value: params.PRODUCT_RELEASE)]
  },
  bla1: {
    sleep(60)
    build job: 'sd_regression',
    parameters: [string(name: 'ARRAY', value: "${params.ARRAY}"), string(name: 'email_recepients', value: "${params.email_recepients}"), string(name: 'test_type', value: 'bla2'), string(name: 'Interface', value: params.interface + '_1'),booleanParam(name: 'Update_UTMS', value: params.Update_UTMS), string(name: 'utms_testset_id', value: "${params.testset_id_2}"), string(name: 'PRODUCT_RELEASE', value: params.PRODUCT_RELEASE)]
  },
  bla3: {
    sleep(120)
    build job: 'sd_regression',
    parameters: [string(name: 'ARRAY', value: "${params.ARRAY}"), string(name: 'email_recepients', value: "${params.email_recepients}"), string(name: 'test_type', value: 'bla3'), string(name: 'Interface', value: params.interface + '_2'),booleanParam(name: 'Update_UTMS', value: params.Update_UTMS), string(name: 'utms_testset_id', value: "${params.testset_id_3}"), string(name: 'PRODUCT_RELEASE', value: params.PRODUCT_RELEASE)]
  },
  bla4: {
    sleep(180)
    build job: 'sd_regression',
    parameters: [string(name: 'ARRAY', value: "${params.ARRAY}"), string(name: 'email_recepients', value: "${params.email_recepients}"), string(name: 'test_type', value: 'bla4'), string(name: 'Interface', value: params.interface + '_3'),booleanParam(name: 'Update_UTMS', value: false), string(name: 'utms_testset_id', value: "${params.testset_id_4}"), string(name: 'PRODUCT_RELEASE', value: params.PRODUCT_RELEASE)]
  },
  bla5: {
    sleep(240)
    build job: 'sd_regression',
    parameters: [string(name: 'ARRAY', value: "${params.ARRAY}"), string(name: 'email_recepients', value: "${params.email_recepients}"), string(name: 'test_type', value: 'bla5'), string(name: 'Interface', value: params.interface + '_4'),booleanParam(name: 'Update_UTMS', value: params.Update_UTMS), string(name: 'utms_testset_id', value: "${params.testset_id_5}"), string(name: 'PRODUCT_RELEASE', value: params.PRODUCT_RELEASE)]
  },
  failFast: false)
}

def suite2() {
  parallel(
  bla6: {
    build job: 'sd_regression',
    parameters: [string(name: 'ARRAY', value: "${params.ARRAY}"), string(name: 'email_recepients', value: "${params.email_recepients}"), string(name: 'test_type', value: 'bla6'), string(name: 'Interface', value: params.interface + '_0'), string(name: 'utms_testset_id', value: "${params.testset_id_1}"), string(name: 'PRODUCT_RELEASE', value: params.PRODUCT_RELEASE)]
  },
  bla7: {
    sleep(60)
    build job: 'sd_regression',
    parameters: [string(name: 'ARRAY', value: "${params.ARRAY}"), string(name: 'email_recepients', value: "${params.email_recepients}"), string(name: 'test_type', value: 'bla7'), string(name: 'Interface', value: params.interface + '_1'), string(name: 'utms_testset_id', value: "${params.testset_id_2}"), string(name: 'PRODUCT_RELEASE', value: params.PRODUCT_RELEASE)]
  },
  bla8: {
    sleep(180)
    build job: 'sd_regression',
    parameters: [string(name: 'ARRAY', value: "${params.ARRAY}"), string(name: 'email_recepients', value: "${params.email_recepients}"), string(name: 'test_type', value: 'bla8'), string(name: 'Interface', value: params.interface + '_3'), string(name: 'utms_testset_id', value: "${params.testset_id_3}"), string(name: 'PRODUCT_RELEASE', value: params.PRODUCT_RELEASE)]
  },
  bla9: {
    sleep(240)
    build job: 'sd_regression',
    parameters: [string(name: 'ARRAY', value: "${params.ARRAY}"), string(name: 'email_recepients', value: "${params.email_recepients}"), string(name: 'test_type', value: 'bla9'), string(name: 'Interface', value: params.interface + '_4'), string(name: 'utms_testset_id', value: "${params.testset_id_4}"), string(name: 'PRODUCT_RELEASE', value: params.PRODUCT_RELEASE)]
  },
  failFast: false)
}
```

Here I have input parameter called **regression_suite** which has option called **all**.
If **all** is selected, then user would provide comma separated values to parameter **testset_all** (example: 1,2,3,4,5).

I want a code where I would read these values and split them and store it in variables. I would then substitute these values to my job params. 
Example: 
var_1= 1 
var_2= 2 
var_3= 3 and so on.
Thank you.

Comment: The only way this is going to work is if either 1. the length of `testset_all` never changes (not feasible) 2. you store these values in a Map instead of individual variables, because dynamic variable naming is not possible if I recall correctly.

Comment: @MattSchuchard can you provide me with a sample code to refer. I can try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use below pipeline script, I have looped through array and printed the value, instead echo statement you can assign that to a variable.

```
def loop_func(values){
    values.each {
        item -> echo "Hello ${item}"
    }
}
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'regression_suite', choices: ['suite1', 'suite2', 'all'], description: '')
        string(name: 'testset_all', defaultValue: '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', description: 'All of Testset IDs')
    }
    stages {
        stage ("Test Stage"){
            when {
                expression {
                    "${params.regression_suite}" == "all"
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    def values = "${params.testset_all}".split(',')
                    loop_func(values)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Updated:

```
def loop_func(values){
    for (int i=0; i<values.size();i++) {
        env."var_${i}"=values[i]
    }
}
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'regression_suite', choices: ['suite1', 'suite2', 'all'], description: '')
        string(name: 'testset_all', defaultValue: '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', description: 'All of Testset IDs')
    }
    stages {
        stage ("Test Stage"){
            when {
                expression {
                    "${params.regression_suite}" == "all"
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    def values = "${params.testset_all}".split(',')
                    loop_func(values)
                    echo "The final Value is : ${env.var_6}"
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Test Stage2"){
            steps{
                echo "${env.var_8}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each step in my script calls for a build job where params are different. I cannot use the above logic here. My need is to have the values saved in some parameter. Example: var_1=1, var_2=2 and so on. So that I can hardcode the var values in each of my build job and only the values keep changing as per user input

Comment: In above logic I have printed the value, are you looking for logic to assign those to a variable ?

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. Can you please help me with one more thing. I want to now use this values (i.e. items) in my various stage of the pipeline. To explain further, say loop iterates 5 times (i.e. $item value is 1,2,3,4,5). I want to store these 5 values in separate variables and use each variable in different stage. Can you please help me by enhancing your above script to fetch the values, store in variable and pass it across stage.

Comment: As per your requirement you are looking for variable accessible across different stages in the script, it can be achieved by global variable but in your case we don't know variable name until it gets populated so I think the best way is to set that as a environment variable and access it across. I have added updated script above. Please let me it answers your question

Comment: Thank you Kiruba. It worked. Highly appreciate your support.